# how to attach image and location to email in android sdk?

Tags: android, image, email, location

hi iam developing an android app in it we can take photo and send it to default email i implement capturing of image with MeadiaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

and i get location by using location.getLatitude() , location.getLongitude();

then how to attach this image and location to email like subject as email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to store the captured image in sdcard and the Use this code to send email

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setType("application/image");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail});
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From App");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg"));
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: @Vamsismart pass your location in EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: is it possible to send location like in whatsapp.

Comment: Refer this link it will give you the address https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html